# Why does dependency injection require another language?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I'm comfortable programming in Java, but am fairly new to Spring.  I've been reading about dependency-injection/inversion of control (and using it with Spring for the past few months), but I can't figure out the need for a separate language (xml/spring) to accomplish it.

What is wrong with creating a singleton in Java called DependencyHandler, and keeping everything in the same language?  What are the advantages I get by using xml/Spring?

Comment: Dependency Injection has to do with the way your application is designed. It can be implemented in many ways, I don't know a whole lot about spring, but I imagine that using XML is the way that spring implements dependency injection

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dependency Injection does not require a separate language.

Spring is a framework for Java that historically required configuration in xml.  Now you can configure it using xml, or java annotations.

Google's Guice is a simple dependency injection framework that has all configuration in Java.

Answer (score 3):

There can be legitimate reasons why a custom language (in xml) can be better than Java for a specific purpose. For DI though, the reasons are stretchy, and in fact, not the real reasons.

From countless testimonies from happy Spring users, the overwhelming reason is that they somehow think xml is not code. They are so tired of writing boilerplate Java code, they are happy to switch to boilerplate xml. And that makes them happy.

Human beings are not rational when it comes to economic matters. We have elaborate systems that transfer resources in circles, finding comfort and security in such pointless waste of efforts.

But I guess happiness is the most important thing, however retarded it could be.

Comment: I upvoted for the second paragraph, because this is how I feel as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can make dependency injection frameworks that use Java syntax, too. Just look at [Google Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/), for example.

Answer (score 0):

Spring is just an easy way to manage dependency injection in large projects.

But you can inject dependencies by using a static factory method on your class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo static mkFoo(/* dependencies */)
    {
        // assign dependencies to members
    }

    // ordinary class stuff
}
```

Then you just do `Foo.mkFoo(/*dependencies*/)` whenever you want a `Foo`. No spring *required*.

> What is wrong with creating a singleton in Java called DependencyHandler, and keeping everything in the same language?

Handling all your dependencies in a single class is going to get messy quickly, and will result in coupling with all of your other classes. But that isn't a reason to not handle DI in plain java.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer the "benefits" part for XML specifically, although there aren't many.

Having configuration completely separate from code removes all framework artifacts from the source, which can be beneficial.

It's easier (not ridiculously so, but enough to be noteworthy) to create toolchains that affect configuration files: property loading/replacement, config-aware  GUI config editors, documentation generation, etc.

Centralized configuration; instead of config being strewn around the codebase, it's in a group of files (or single file). This isn't an XML-only vitrue, it depends on how things are configured.

I think some types of configuration lend themselves to external configuration more than others. I choose based on what seems appropriate given the reqs, what the framework allows, and how the framework handles config aspects.